# filter in ui-select in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to display element of the first array objectcalled: hotels[{code, namehotel, sizehotel}] without the element that exist in the second array object called : usersHotels[{code, id}] using the filter in ui-select:

this is my code:

```
<ui-select autofocus ng-model="nameHotelSelected" theme="select2"  ng-change="changedValue(this)"  align="center" style="width: 500px">
<ui-select-match placeholder="link this contact to  ...">{{text}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="user in usersHotel  ">
<ui-select-choices repeat="nameHotel in hotels  | filter: nameHotel.code:'user.code'">

<span ng-bind="nameHotel.name"></span>
</ui-select-choices>
```

is it right to do that? if not how to do that ?

Comment: Your question is actually confusing. What are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Anees Muhammed i want to get the element that doesn't exist in the usersHotels from hotels using angular js. as usersHotels and hotels are array of object? i hope you understand my question.